# "Is" instead of "are" with many

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, contractions

In spoken English I often hear a contraction of **Why is** used with **many+plural noun**. Is that acceptable informal language or should it be avoided?

- **Why's there so many books on the table?** instead of **Why are there so many books on the table?**
- **Why's there so many people in our house today?** instead of **Why are there so many people in our house today?**

Comment: In colloquial English, agreement in number is often ignored. English speakers don't consult a grammar text in the course of their daily lives. I hope that speakers of your own language don't do so! Avoid this usage in formal writing, but don't worry about it beyond that.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Okay, so that's okay in spoken English. I hope non-native speakers can speak like that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When using existential **there** constructions*, a phrase like **so many people in the house today** is often understood to be a single "existential" fact and is thus grammatically singular not plural.

Absent a *there*-construction, native speakers would not tend to say

> Why is so many people in the house today? <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

but they would often say

> Why's there so many people in the house today?